# DOMPDF fails to render font, shows circles instead

Tags: php, css, pdf, fonts, dompdf

Followed this guide: [github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo)

Used the `load_font.php` script, confirmed the font files were copied to `/dompdf/lib/fonts` and the font information was added to the fonts cache file. Included the `font-family` to the CSS file.

When I try to render a PDF it shows me circles instead of characters. I'd make a screenshot, but I can't since Adobe Reader crashes right after loading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The files were copied to `/dompdf/lib/fonts` from wherever I uploaded them to without any changes.
2. The DOMPDF fonts cache file lists the font names without any extension.

The problem here was that apparently, it then searches for the TTF files assuming the lowercase extension, while the ones I uploaded were in uppercase, they were not renamed, and could not be found since the server file system is case-sensitive.

**TL;DR** make sure the extensions of the font files you've uploaded are all in lowercase

Comment: @BrianS thank you for the amazing tool! If you have time, please update the `load_font.php` to take care of the issue automatically by, I guess, just force-renaming the files extensions to lowercase. Thanks again

Comment: I haven't yet seen this particular issue. Thanks for finding it, might be helpful for others having font issues. I added a bug: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1002.